# Exporting JAR with multiple JFrames

Tags: java, jar, export

I know how to export a Jar file and have many times before.
With my current project I was able to export and run it perfectly fine, but as soon as I added another JFrame into the project whenever I click the button to load it, the JFrame will not load and instead the JAR just freezes. Doesn't crash or anything, simply Freezes.
Is this a common problem? What can be done to fix it?

First JFrame

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public Launcher(int id) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setTitle("Launcher");
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    window.setLayout(null);
```

Code to open second JFrame

```
if (Input.Clicked == 1) {
    config.loadConfig("res/Config/config.xml");
    frame.dispose();
    new NewLauncher();

}
```

Code for NewLauncher()

```
    public NewLauncher() {

    Display app = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(app);
    frame.setSize(Display.getGameWidth(), Display.getGameHeight());
    frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setTitle(Display.TITLE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    game.start();
    stopMenuThread();
}
```

EDIT WITH EventQueue

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
       public void run()
       {
        new Launcher(0);
       }
    });
    //new Launcher(0);
}
```

Code runs fine in the debugger and compiler. Still won't run in Jar, am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Code please. Does it work out side of the Jar?

Comment: The code for the new JFrame?
Yeah it runs perfectly in the Compiler and while 'Debugging'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running the UI in the Event Dispatching Thread

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 // Run your code here ...
});
```

Make sure you are not doing any time consuming tasks on the Event Dispatching Thread, including, sleeping or waiting on any locks

Comment: This wold go anywhere before you create your frames where you cannot guarantee that you are running on the EDT

Comment: Just edited code. Sorry I have never used EventQueue before and can't find much on how to properly use it.
Am I using it correctly?

Comment: It depends on what `game.start()` and `stopMenuThread()` are doing. If they block in anyway, then it will prevent the EDT from process paint requests or handle events...

Comment: You might like to read through [Taming Swing Threads Part 2: Common Event Queue Pitfalls](http://www.javaswingcomponents.com/blog/taming-swing-threads-part-2-common-event-queue-pitfalls) and [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)